# Random "red x" warning but no information given. Where should I start?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm new some I apologize if this sounds stupid.

I'm using the latest version of Eclipse and and have an "Android Project" going. I have a little red x on one of my folders. Usually a "pop" will tell me what is wrong but this one says nothing. When I open activity_main.xml (which is inside the folder there are no problems that I can see). Is this a glitch or is this normal?

I'm not sure where to start to make it go away.

How I got there;

I started a new folder under "res". I'm following a book and it said to call it Layout Land and start another activity_main.xml inside. Everything is fine but that x is there over the folder.

Any info will help. Thanks!

Comment: In Eclipse go to Window -> Show View -> and open Problems and Error Log. Are there any errors listed there?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window -> Show View -> Problems. Then you should have a Window in which you can read what the problem is.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I actually found some one else had the same problem on this site and they gave the same answer you gave. So what's my problem? "Problems" under "Show View" isn't there. I clicked on "Other" but I did not see "Problems" listed.

Comment: Please take a screenshot of your Eclipse enviroment and post it here :)

Comment: As you can see "problems" is not listed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Never mind. It wasn't listed but I searched for it and it came up. It was in Show View > Window > Other > General > Problems. It worked too, unlike in the usual places, the problem was listed here! Eclipse say's it's an "invalid resource directory name". Now I'm on the right "path". Thanks again!